# Constructing an SQL query with time intervals

Tags: sqlite

I've a simple but large table in an SQL database which has four fields:

```
id    (int PK)
time  (unix timestamp, not null)
value (double, not null) 
ID_fk (integer foreign key)
```

Data is recorded every minute, but at a seemingly random second for subsets of sensors, each sensor has a foreign key value though.

My question is this:

- I need to write a query that will tell me when, over all two minute intervals in the dataset, a series of sensors have a value greater than 0.9.

I was thinking for trying to create a temporary table and do it that way, simplifying the time by only storing it at minute resolution?

Any advice would be greatly received.

Comment: You've tagged the question with SQLite - is that what you're using? Just double checking :)

Comment: All two minute intervals or all two minute "whole" intervals - e.g. are you bucketing the data by interval, or do you want to see all possible intervals (e.g. any span of time that is 2 minutes (to the second?) or just a bucketed set of minutes?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a [CTE recursive function](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html#recursive_common_table_expressions) that generates a time series.

There is an [answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32987070/3270427) that shows how to do it:

```
WITH RECURSIVE dates(StartDate, EndDate) AS 
(
    VALUES('2016-10-01 00:00:00', '2016-10-01 00:00:02')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT EndDate as StartDate, datetime(EndDate, '+2 seconds') as EndDate
    FROM   dates
    WHERE  EndDate < '2016-10-02 00:00:00'
)
SELECT     your_table.*
FROM       your_table
CROSS JOIN dates
WHERE      value > 0.9
AND        time >= StartDate
AND        time <  EndDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

For every line, you check that there are no lines in the previous 2 seconds with value smaller than 0.9 (therefore they all are greater than 0.9).

```
select * from table outer_table where value > 0.9 and not exists (
    select * from table where value <= 0.9 and (outer_table.time - time) <= 2
)
```